# Relations between the Latin squares of order n and the groups of order n.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, latin-square

Given a group $g$ of order $n\in \mathbb{N}$, it is clear that its Cayley table has the Latin square property. That is, every row and column of the Cayley table contains precisely the elements of $g$. Therefore, a natural question is as follows:

> Fix $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Suppose that $G_n$ is the set of all groups of
>   order $n$ and $L_n$ is the set of all Latin squares of order $n$. We
>   shall then define the relation $R\subset G_n \times L_n$ by
>   $(g,\ell)\in R$ iff there exists a labeling of the elements of $g$
>   such that the Cayley table of $g$, ignoring the headings, is $\ell$, for $g\in G_n$ and
>   $\ell\in L_n$. What are the properties of $R$?

It's not too hard to see that every group $g$ of order $n$ is related to $n!$ Latin squares, because permuting the elements of $g$ in its Cayley table will produce different Latin squares.

Suppose that $RL_n$ is the set of all reduced Latin rectangles of order $n$, then we have that each $g\in G_n$ is related to a unique $\ell\in RL_n$. Thus, the relation $R'\subset G_n \times RL_n$, defined similarly to R as above, is in fact a mapping. It is clear that $R'$ is not an injective mapping, because if $g,h\in G_n$ are isomorphic, then $g$ and $h$ will both be related to the same $\ell \in RL_n$. Furthermore, $R'$ is not, for a general $n$, surjective. This is because some Latin squares are only related, in the "natural" fashion, to non-associative quasi-groups. So, yet another question naturally arises:

> Suppose that im$(R')$ is the set of all $\ell\in RL_n$ such that
>   $(g,\ell)\in R'$ for some $g\in G_n$. What are the properties of
>   $\ell\in RL_n \cap im(R')^C?$ Well, obviously such an $\ell$ will be
>   related to, in the "natural" fashion, to a non-associative
>   quasi-group. However, what is it about the structure of the Latin
>   square specifically that is not shared by the Cayley table of any
>   group?

Comment: What are you looking for in your second question beyond that the square doesn't satisfy the associative law?  That is, $\ell$ is not in the image of $R'$ if and only if there exist $i,j,k \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ so that $\ell(i,\ell(j,k)) \ne \ell(\ell(i,j),k)$.

Comment: You don't take into account that you can permute the rows or the symbols independently of the columns (or vice-versa) and still have a latin square (or rectangle) for that matter. There are evident normalizations, symmetries and overlaps so latin squares/rectangles arising from group Cayley tables will exhibit a lot less variety upon these transformations than latin squares coming from very nonassociative quasigroups and loops.