# How many representations of a non-commutative groups from $n$-dimensional Latin Squares

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, latin-square

I would like to know if there is a method to determine how many $n \times n$ Latin square define the same non-commutative group $G$. This is how many representations of $G$ can be obtained from $n$ dimensional Latin squares.

It results that I'm interested on building examples of non-abelian groups to toy with and test how many representations do they have.

Comment: Symmetric groups appear everywhere (so are ideal for toy examples). Any group table is a Latin square, see for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square_property). For a given Latin square we have its automorphism group. See also the other posts at this site, e.g., [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1360228/relations-between-the-latin-squares-of-order-n-and-the-groups-of-order-n) and its links.

Comment: Concretely the table can be built using the principle from the action of $f: G \times G \to G$ so $f(a,b)=c$ If I'm correct such representation is the core of Cayley's theorem as the group would be embedded into a permutation group (if it's action is faithful). My concern here is to build arbitrary non-abelian groups of order $n$ and to obtain the different number of Latin squares that define the same non-abelian group. I should point that on my question.

Comment: Then why aren't you just taking the known non-abelian groups, e.g., all finite simple non-abelian groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm going to assume that the elements of the Latin Square are the elements of the group. If that's not what you want, then make your question clearer.)

For a given group, once you've chosen how you label the rows and columns, the Cayley table is uniquely determined. So if the group has order $n$, it has $(n!)^2$ tables.